# Time difference is not returning the expected result in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, time

```
select '06:00:00'::TIME - ('19:00:00'::TIME - '07:00:23.388471'::TIME);
+-----------------+
| ?column?        |
|-----------------|
| 18:00:23.388471 |
+-----------------+
SELECT 1
Time: 0.012s
```

Why isn't it returning a negative result? I'm using the latest version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yo u are substracting from a time value (`'06:00:00'`) an interval (the result of `('19:00:00'::TIME - '07:00:23.388471'::TIME)`). The result of `time - interval` is a time value. And time values are only between `'00:00:00'` and `'24:00:00'`

Comment: Try for example: `select '06:00:00'::TIME, '06:00:00'::TIME + interval '24 hour', '06:00:00'::TIME - interval '24 hour' ;`. You'll get three identical values.